# How to upload files in grails webflow?

Tags: grails, file-upload, upload, spring-webflow

I try to build a grails webflow containing a step which has a file upload field in it. Can't find a clear example. How can I do it?

The form looks like this:

```
<g:form method="POST" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload! " />
</g:form>
```

The flow looks like this:

```
def rgdpsRequestFlow = {
    chargeCheck{
        on("upload"){ 
            println "Hello file upload"
        }.to("uploadSuccess")
    }
    uploadSuccess{

    }
}
```

When I submit the form I get

```
HTTP Status 404 - /webflowTest/mortgage/upload
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I used *g:form action* attribute.
The correct way to use file upload with webflow is using *g:submitButton*

Here is the form code that works fine with my webflow:

```
<g:form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myFile" />
    <g:submitButton class="save" name="upload" value="Upload!"/>
</g:form>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a little unclear which part you're struggling with.  If you need help with the file upload, you may want to try the [Grails File Uploader plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/file-uploader), or otherwise check out this [step-by-step tutorial](http://www.slideshare.net/cavneb/upload-files-with-grails) or use the [uploadForm](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Tags/uploadForm.html) tag that James Kleeh has pointed out.

Namely, in the gsp you can add:

```
<g:uploadForm controller='yourControllerName' action='save'>
    <input type='file' name='file'/>
    <input type='submit'/>
</g:uploadForm>
```

Then handle it in the controller:

```
def save = {
    def file = request.getFile('file').inputStream.text
    file.transferTo(new File('someLocation/filename'))
}
```

Comment: Theres a shortcut for that `<g:uploadForm />`

Comment: @GrailsGuy, I am struggling with **Grails Webflow** + **file upload**. Each of them work good, but not together. Upload action does not hit the step in a webflow, it routes somewhere else. I'll upldate the post with some code.

Comment: @GrailsGuy I answered my question.